# Xperia L C2105: Wifi not turning on after installing Android 5.1.1

Tags: custom-roms, 5.1-lollipop, wifi-hotspot, flashtool, sony-xperia-l

I have installed latest Android 5.1.1 from the website https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=taoshan. I have done this with the help of the following steps.

1. Unlocked the phone and root it with the help of flash tool before it I have latest stock ROM installed on my phone.
2. Using flash tool I flashes the CWD recovery.
3. Downloaded the ROM from the website mentioned before and copied to SD Card.
4. Rebooted the phone and by press volume + goes to CWD recovery.
5. From recovery menu I did "Wipe data/factory reset", "Wipe Cache partition" and "Wipe delvik cache".
6. From recovery menu I select "install from zip"->"install zip from SD Card" and then selected the ROM zip file.
7. I Also installed gapps zip file after. Both are installed successfully.
8. Rebooted the phone and the apps installation completed.

Blue-tooth, Camera, mobile data and all others apps working good. Also the speed of my phone greatly improves and the phone memory shortage issue solved. The only issue I have is the Wifi and hotspot is not turning on at all.

I have tried 5.0 and previous versions of 5.1.1 also some unofficial versions by repeating the same steps (2-8) but having the same issue. Any idea what I done wrong?

Comment: Thanks! Time for comment-cleanup then. Good luck with your question – unfortunately, I've got no idea there.

Comment: Two things you need to do: 1) go back to stock ROM and verify that your device can enable Wi-Fi/ connect to it and create hotspot. I'm just excluding any possibility of hardware issue. When confirmed that there is no failure, flash custom ROM and when enabling the Wi-Fi or hotspot, log your actions using [tag:logcat] (see [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1726238), if you're new to logcat) and post us your results using an online text/code paste service.

Comment: As @Firelord said, [Flash the appropriate stock ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-l/general/sony-xperia-l-flashable-ftfs-locked-t2560642) using a [flash tool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-l/general/xperia-l-how-to-flash-tool-unlocking-t2337955).

Comment: @Firelord I will try logcat and will let you know the results

Comment: With Stock ROM, Wifi was working. I just checked with Catlog it give me error msg "WifiService Machine:E:Failed to load driver".